# Application to avoid me waiting in call centre phone queue

Tags: android, ios, productivity

I am looking for an Android or iOS application that could wait for me when I have to go through a call centre phone queue (typically when trying to reach a customer service, which can take one hour or more). For example, I would start the application when I begin queuing, then the application would alert me when the queue is over.

In most cases, it should be possible to detect when the human operator starts talking to me. Another less clever but more reliable way to do it would be to simply have a database of music used in those queues and detect when they stop.

I am also okay if the application works on Windows or Mac, in which case I guess I would call through VoIP.

To put it [visually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_queue):

[image]

(Btw [waiting on the phone for more than six minutes can be bad for health](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2040375/Waiting-centre-queue-minutes-bad-health.html).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [**FastCustomer**](http://www.fastcustomer.com/) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=www.fastcustomer.com), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fast-customer-productivity/id421471487?mt=8&ls=1)).

The system works by using a database of known queuing systems and navigating them for you until it reaches an agent, then calling *you* so you can get on the line. It won't work for unknown systems but it is pretty effective at getting through to some of the most common offenders in the customer support phone tree world.

There is a brief [video review](https://ting.com/blog/app-of-the-week-fastcustomer/) on Ting's app-pick blog.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app (available for both Android and iOS) called [WeQ4u](http://www.weq4u.co.uk/) which does exactly what you want for calls in the UK. It also allows you to make calls to UK 08 numbers for free.

> To use it, just enter the number you wish to reach and the app will
>   connect you. If you get stuck in a queue, just press 9* on your
>   telephone keypad, and your phone will disconnect from the call.

**EDIT:** Just noticed you're in the US... I don't know of a similar app in the US but this answer might be useful for UK people.