# Android program to navigate automated customer service and wake on representative

Tags: android, productivity, mobile

I'm having to waste too much time navigating automatic customer service numbers. For example, I'd call my cell phone provider, and then I need to press 1 for English, and then wait as they go over all the options, and then 2 for customer service, then lots of options again... Then press 3 for non-business customers... etc. In some cases you can simply press all these numbers without listening to the explanations if you know what you want, but in many cases you can't, there's specific times you need to wait for the explanations to play out.

Then I need to wait for a representative, which is another maddening waste of time.

**What I want is an app that initiates the call, lets me choose the choices in advance without waiting, and then waits for a representative for me. When everything is done and a representative is available, then it sounds a notification so I'll come to the phone.**

Is there an app like that for Android? Does it actually work?

Comment: We had a question like that a while ago (at least 6+ month ago that is). Unfortunately this topic is hard to "tag", making a search not that easy. But while waiting for answers, I recommend skimming over "old questions" (or use our [search] with different keywords), you might be lucky! // Ah, yes: [Application to avoid me waiting in call centre phone queue](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4330/185)